# aws s3 override default config

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Good Afternoon,

i have default config file for aws which looks like this:

```
[default]
region = XXXXXX
aws_secret_access_key =XXXXXXXXXXX
ws_access_key_id = XXXXXXXX
```

i want to override these config variables while initializing the aws.s3:

```
let albumName = CONSTANTS.AWS.ALBUM;
let id = CONSTANTS.AWS.KEY;
let bucketRegion = CONSTANTS.AWS.REGION;
let secret = CONSTANTS.AWS.SECRET;

var s3 = new AWS.S3({
  apiVersion: '2006-03-01',
  secretAccessId: id,
  secretAccessKey: secret,
  region: bucketRegion,
  params: {
    Bucket: albumName
  }
});
```

but i am getting the same old key i tried using aws s3 update command but its not working as well. how can i override it.
iam using it to upload image in an album with the command code:

```
var albumPhotosKey = encodeURIComponent(albumName) + '//';
    var photoKey = albumPhotosKey + name;
    var fileStream = fs.createReadStream(req.body.files.path);
    fileStream.on('error', function (err) {
      if (err) { throw err; }
    });
    fileStream.on('open', function () {
      s3.putObject({
        Key: photoKey,
        Body: fileStream,
        ACL: 'public-read'
      }, function (err, data) {
        if (err) {
          console.log('There was an error uploading your photo: ', err.message);
        } else {
          console.log('Success', data);
        }
      });
    });
```

Thank you.

Comment: What is the error? Why are you putting the bucket name in `s3`? It should be passed to `putObject()`. Also, why do you wish to override the settings — are you wanting to use multiple clients in the program?

Comment: yes actually we had multiple aws keys and secret so were trying to override the default value with the parameters while calling aws.s3 or s3.config.update. i had seen a implementation like so and tried doing the same for the buckname params.the error i was getting is message: "access denied"

Answer (score 0):

Use aws cli command, `aws configure`. This will prompt to enter the access key id, secret, default region and output file. If you want to keep the current value just press enter.

Comment: I will give it a try. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can update config at run time.

`AWS.config.update({region:'us-east-1'});`

Comment: this doesn't seem to work i have mentioned it in the question that i have tried the update. method of aws. Thank you.